# Winrt phone 8.1 StackPanel Visibility Animation

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a vertical `stackpanel` with almost 10 `textblocks` in it whose visibility changes on a button click, Can we apply animations on visibility of a `stackpanel` mean when it collapse or visible it shows animation like it is open from top.

I don't know it is possible or not. Or easily achievable or not.

Comment: Well best is to look at Storyboards https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example of using AddDelete Transition Animation:
https://www.dropbox.com/l/9hcyf0V4q6qimmpvwal7no

**Explanation:**
You can apply all sorts of animations achieve what you're wanting and it can get pretty complex.  The easiest solution I've found is to use AddDeleteThemeTransition animation.  First, you'll need to reference Media.Animation under Windows.UI.Xaml:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
```

You would need to maintain a collection of your textblocks because instead altering the visibility on them, you'll actually remove them completely from the stackpanel.

Module Level variable:

```
List<TextBlock> textblocks = new List<TextBlock>();
```

Here you would programatically add your text boxes to the List.

```
        Transition addDelete = new AddDeleteThemeTransition();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Transitions = new TransitionCollection();
            textBlock.Transitions.Add(addDelete);
            textBlock.Text = "Test Textblock " + i;
            //set font size, style, etc...
            textblocks.Add(textBlock);
        }
```

Once you have the AddDeleteThemeTransition on the textblocks, you can perform the following:

```
    private async Task showTextBlocks()
    {
        foreach (TextBlock tb in textblocks)
        {
            stackPanel.Children.Add(tb);
            await Task.Delay(50); //If you want them to stagger on... remove if not to stagger
        }
    }

    private async Task hideTextBlocks()
    {
        //remove the textblocks in reverse order
        for (int i = textblocks.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            TextBlock tb = textblocks[i];
            stackPanel.Children.Remove(tb);
            await Task.Delay(50); //if you want them to stagger off... remove if not to stagger
        }
    }
```

Because the textblock elements have a AddDeleteThemeTransition  transition applied to them, they'll animate when they are added or removed from the stack panel.

This will give AN animation... not a lot of control over it but you can play around with it to see if it gets you what you need.

For a list of other Transition types, you can view Microsoft Documentation [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj218361.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve what you want using just xaml. A storyboard and an EventTriggerBehavior is what you need. If you are interested I can put together a sample with code.